# How to determine site web root on Shared Hosting and set up a Scheduled Task?

Tags: cron, plesk

I am still new in doing a scheduled task. My problem is where should I put the PHP script I will make?
In creating a Schedule Task I need to fill up this:

```
Specify the full path to the script. Example: /tmp/script.php
```

How can I get the full path? I already created a web user in my domain.
Example in my domain I will put my script inside my `sample_website` So my full path will be like this?

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/my_domain.ph/public_html/sample_website/cron_script.php
```

Please help me guys. I am still new in doing this. Thanks

Can you provide me a step by step process with this?

Answer (score 0):

To determine your script server full path you always can create PHP script with content:

```
<?php

echo(__FILE__);
```

and place it in your web root, like /httpdocs/script.php

Than you access it via browser like `http://you-domain.name/script.php`

It will show your web root path on server it should be something like:

```
/var/www/vhosts/you-domain.name/httpdocs/script.php
```

Now you know that your files are placed at `/var/www/vhosts/you-domain.name/httpdocs/` and can use it to call scripts from scheduled tasks.